# Problems reading data from Binary store from tmp folder

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Getting this error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle16425735337117079234.bin offset 753438 exists? true
```

Result of `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Manjaro Linux 5.15.32-1-MANJARO, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Content of android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this. In my case it was

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```

switched to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:6'
```

in the app/build.gradle file.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/20515#issuecomment-1121012872

Answer (score 1):

Same. Repository failure? I haven't changed any of the underlying android grade files etc. I wonder if it's something to do wit jcenter() being offline now...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes `jcenter` is not working for some of the libraries.

Removing `jcenter()` from `android/build.gralde` fixed this issue.
Also, make sure all your libraries are present on `maven`.
Or else you will get an "Not Found" error while building.

Comment: Hey Kapil, I tried to remove `jcenter()` but issue still persists.

Comment: Have you removed all the jcenter() calls from the file ?
Keeping any one of them can cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) `4.1`, which matches these build tools:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
```

eg. for Android Studio Chipmunk, this would already be `7.2.0`. And remove `jcenter()`.

Answer (score 0):

in app level build.gradle
change this line
// implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
to
this
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:6'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change this line in build.gradle

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[4,5)'

to this

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5'

OR
This implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

to this

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:6'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 4 days trying to solve this issue and finally I found the solution for my project. For me, the problem was with the library `location: ^2.3.5`, once I removed my project came back to life.

What I recommend to do: copy your project folder, replace `/lib` with the standard flutter create template and start removing dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` one by one until you find which one is causing the problem.